# how to delete an item in recycleview from another activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I am working on an expense tracker app. When I click on item in recycleview, it takes me to another activity where I have two buttons : update and delete. The issue is I don't get the idea how to delete item from recycleview, which is in another activity, when delete button in that activity is pressed. Actually, I also searched and looked up other similar questions and answers on stack overflow however that didn't help me. If someone can help me on this, I will appreciate it greatly.

This is my code where I am passing the position of my item :

```
final int pos = holder.getAdapterPosition();
        holder.date.setText(MyModel.getDate());
        holder.note.setText(MyModel.getNote());
        holder.Btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(context,Update_transaction.class);
                i.putExtra("key",myViewsList.get(pos).getId());
                i.putExtra("pos",holder.getAdapterPosition());
                context.startActivity(i);

            }
        });
```

This is the code where I am retrieving the data in another activity :

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        Update_db = new DataSaver(this);
        if(bundle != null)
        {
            id = bundle.getString("key");
            pos = bundle.getString("pos");
            Toast.makeText(this, "pos : " + pos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: If you started the second activity with start activity for result then at ending the second activity you can put in the intent if and which item has to be deleted. In onActivityResult of first activity you read that intent and handle accordingly. You delete the item from a list for the adapter for the recycle view.

Comment: The problem is I am also handling with sqlite database as well. When delete button is pressed, that particular item needs to be deleted in sqlite database, and then in recycleview.

Comment: Well, ok. Do it. Whats the problem exactly?

Comment: Sir, I have tried your method. It worked to some extent however the problem now I am facing is that item' position couldn't pass to another activity. @blackapps

Comment: You have only start activity. Not start activity for result

Comment: you can override the @onResume method on first activity to refresh the recyclerview. When you delete the item in the second activity it gets deleted from the database and when you come back to the first activity the onResume method get called and new list is fetched to the recyclerview from the database.

Answer (score 0):

For interaction between activities, you can use the LocalBroadcastManager.  You can send a broadcast from one activity and receive it in another.

**Send broadcast**

```
val intent = Intent("ACTION")
intent.putExtra("needUpdate", true)
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent)
```

**Receive broadcast**

1.Create a listener

```
val myBroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
   override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
       println("Your value: " + intent?.getStringExtra("needUpdate"))
   }
}
```

Register

```
override fun onResume() {
   // …
   val filter = IntentFilter("ACTION")
   LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(applicationContext).registerReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver, filter)
}
```

Cancel registration

```
override fun onPause() {
   // …
   LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(applicationContext).unregisterReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver)
}
```

More details: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts